# My view in cakephp give error "Call to a member function create() on a non-object ",why?

Tags: cakephp

View contain following code:-

```
<?php 
 echo $form->create('Post',array('action'=>'add'));
 echo $form->input('title');
 echo $form->input('body');
 echo $form->end("Create a post");
```

?>

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using. It also helps to read the official documentation.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the official documentation it is not

```
$form
```

but

```
$this->Form
```

And that since CakePHP1.3